# Ember.js action bubbling but controller undefined in action

Tags: ember.js, event-bubbling, ember-router, ember-controllers

I have a route that has an `afterModel` hook.

```
afterModel: function(model, transition){
  transition.send('doInAppRoute');
}
```

I have an action in my application route:

```
doInAppRoute: function(){
  var controller = this.get('controller');
  controller.set('someProp', true);
}
```

When I allow the action to bubble from the route with the `afterModel` hook, I get the following error.

`Error while processing route: embed Cannot read property 'set' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`

If I put an action call to `doInAppRoute` in the application template, everything runs as expected.

If the action call to `doInAppRoute` bubbles, `this.get('controller')` in my application route is undefined.  Why?

And how can this be changed so the bubbled action updates the application controller property?

Comment: The controller will not be set up until AFTER all the model hooks have resolved.

Comment: I would say keep your state related properties in controller. In your case if you change `someProp` in route then it will not reflect in template unless it passes through setupController.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @torazaburo for leading me in the right direction.

This is what I did.

Set `someProp` to an initial value in application route.

```
someProp: false,
```

Then in the the application route action do something like:

```
doInAppRoute: function(){
  this.set('someProp', true);
}
```

And then in the application route setupController do:

```
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('someProp', this.get('someProp'));
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
```

Then everything should work.

Comment: I suggest calling `this._super(...arguments);` instead of setting the model, it's less prone to bugs.